# Laravel Mail не работает

Tags: php, laravel, email

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<моя gmail почта>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<пароль от google приложения>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
Это был .env
А это код отправки email:

```
$to_name = $name;
$to_email = $email;
$data = array('name'=>"Sam Jose", "body" => "Test mail");
Mail::send('emails', $data, function($message) use ($to_name, $to_email) {
  $message->to($to_email, $to_name)->subject('Artisans Web Testing Mail');
  $message->from('parking.search.itmo@gmail.com','Artisans Web');
});
```

Не понимаю, в чём дело. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе.

Comment: @Сергей, простите, не заметил, что не приложил картинку.

Answer (score 0):

Либо это
[https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/10748445?hl=en#:~:text=Solution,access%20to%20Less%20secure%20apps](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/10748445?hl=en#:%7E:text=Solution,access%20to%20Less%20secure%20apps).

Либо у вас стоит запрет на доступ.